# Sorting realm-js Results on length of Linked Objects array

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Consider the case of having notes and tags. Notes and tags are defined as:

```
export class Note extends Realm.Object {
  public static schema: Realm.ObjectSchema = {
      name: 'Note',
      primaryKey: "_id",
      properties: {
          _id: "string",
          text: 'string',
          date: 'date',
          tags: 'Tag[]'
      }
  }
}

export class Tag extends Realm.Object {
  public static schema: Realm.ObjectSchema = {
      name: 'Tag',
      primaryKey: "name",
      properties: {
          name: 'string',
          notes: {
            type: 'linkingObjects',
            objectType: 'Note',
            property: 'tags'
          }
      }
  }
}
```

For the purpose of an autocomplete for tags I want to sort tags based on the number of notes they appear in, i.e. the length of the notes array, intuitively that means the ability to perform the statement:

```
realm.objects('Tag').sorted('notes.@count')
```

Unfortunately this will result in the error `Error: Cannot sort on key path 'notes.@count': property 'Tag.notes' is of unsupported type 'linking objects'.`

What would be your suggested query for retrieving the tags sorted by frequency in notes?

Comment: Just a clarification; the question mentions 'frequency' but you really mean you want to sort Notes by the number of Tags in their Tags array, correct? Or.. you want to sort Tags by something? It's a bit confusing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Indeed I'd like to sort by the number of Tags in the Tags array.

Comment: I believe what you are asking about is [Sorting By Keypath](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4554) which is very much needed but not currently supported (been open since 2017). If the number of objects is small, it's pretty trivial to do this in code - keeping in mind as soon as you stray away from pure realm objects, the data is loaded into memory and looses it's lazy-loading aspect. I can toss out a Swift solution if that would be helpful. Oh - another simple solution is to maintain a separate property that keeps track of the count of tags. Then sorting is super easy.

Comment: @Jay Thank you for this answer. If you'd have a javascript solution that would be great though.